# File upload: StreamContent vs DTO with byte array

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

There are two approaches I am aware of to upload a file in a Blazor WebAssembly application. One is to use the StreamContent class roughly like so:

```cs
// ...
var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));
// ...
await Http.PostAsync("/file", content);
// ...
```

This approach does usually take two requests when I want to pass additional data with the file.

Another approach is to have a DTO class with all the additional properties and a byte[] array property that contains the file.

I do believe that the first approach with the StreamContent is better. But I can't exactly reason why. I assume it is because I don't have to load the entire file into the client memory first. I can just "stream" it without ever having to allocate too much memory at once. However, is this really a benefit when talking about files that are maybe a couple mega bytes?

Comment: I use Radzen Blazor components, and the [RadzenFileInput (link to source code)](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/blob/master/Radzen.Blazor/RadzenFileInput.razor.cs) use the `byte[]` approach. I didn't found any problem working with regular images, obviously if you must upload backup files or other large objects is better to use a stream, as you already observed. 
Take a look at the component code since in this case it could use also a `string` of `byte[]`, I find this approach very usefull when the data is sent with other simple form values.

Comment: If they're small files, you could send them multiple ways.  Heck, you chould just convert them to base64 and transfer them as a string with no API at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is right regarding both the approaches.

When you use `StreamContent`, the file is sent as a stream. This means that the file is not fully loaded into the memory before being sent to the server. It's read and transmitted in chunks. This is particularly beneficial for large files, as it avoids consuming large amounts of client-side memory.Streaming is more scalable, especially when dealing with multiple or frequent file uploads.For large files, streaming can offer better performance because it starts sending data immediately without waiting for the entire file to be loaded into memory.As you've mentioned, a drawback is when you need to send additional data along with the file. In this case, you might need to make two separate requests or devise a more complex method to send metadata alongside the file.

Using a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with a byte array for the file content and additional properties is straightforward. It's easier to handle when you need to send metadata along with the file.The major drawback is memory consumption. The entire file needs to be loaded into memory before it can be sent. This is fine for small files but when ypu are sending arge files it becomes a problem.

In summary, If you're consistently dealing with larger files lets say tens to hundreds of megabytes, the `StreamContent` approach is preferable due to its efficiency in memory usage and scalability.The byte array method offers simplicity and may be adequate for smaller files or scenarios where the ease of handling additional data outweighs the memory considerations.